# Can Support Vector Regression be used with count data?

Tags: regression, svm, count-data

Can Support Vector Regression be used with count data?
If it can be used for count data, can you give me information about it?

UPDATE: I mean something like a Poisson GLM but using SVR

Comment: Do you mean something like a Poisson GLM but using SVR?

Comment: Yes Dave. I mean that

Comment: Some have tried: https://espace.library.uq.edu.au/view/UQ:687825 https://ceprofs.civil.tamu.edu/dlord/Papers/Li_et_al._SVMs.pdf

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using SVR for most regression tasks as often you have expert knowledge about the noise process, which shouldn't be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Had the exact same question. I knew that Support Vector Machines (SVM) can be used for regression, but wasn't sure whether this extends to a Poisson regression (GLM) for count data. Unfortunately the [link in the comments](https://espace.library.uq.edu.au/view/UQ:687825) gives not much information what was done and how.

Found a paper in the Annals of Data Science from Sidumo et al. (2021) titled [Count Regression and Machine Learning Techniques for Zero-Inflated Overdispersed Count Data: Application to Ecological Data](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40745-023-00464-6). The paper should be open access, but here still the quick details:

The authors compared a Support Vector Regression (SVR) with a Gaussian radial basis function kernel to classical statistical models for count data, i.e. a Poisson, a negative binomial, a zero-inflated Poisson and a zero-inflated negative binomial model. The Gaussian radial basis function kernel is used to model the non-linear relationship between the predictors and outcome. They found that the SVR had the lowest mean absolute error out of all the models. So SVR outperformed the classical statistical methods for a dataset about fish species.

So yes, it is possible to use an SVR on count data.

Answer (score 0):

The ``kernel trick'' can easily be applied to any Generalised Linear Model to give a Generalised Kernel Machine, which includes Poisson regression, see my paper (with a colleague and Mrs Marsupial):

G. C. Cawley, G. J. Janacek and N. L. C. Talbot, Generalised Kernel Machines, in Proceedings of the IEEE/INNS Joint Conference on Neural Networks (IJCNN'07), Orlando, Florida, U.S.A., August 12-17, 2007. ([www](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4371217),[pdf](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/publications/pdf/ijcnn2007a.pdf),[MATLAB software](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/projects/gkm))

This includes a virtual leave-one-out estimator (like Allen's PRESS) that can be used for tuning the hyper-parameters efficiently.  IIRC there is a Poisson regression example in the paper.

NB this is a fairly obvious idea, the paper is mostly just to "advertise" the MATLAB toolbox to anybody that might find it useful.  It had one "fun" (to program) feature which is that it used the MATLAB symbolic maths toolbox to generate the code for different kinds of GKM.